# Replace similar columns with some numerical values

Tags: r, data-science

I have dataframe like this:

```
Hashed_User_Id

[1] f2de2b4a6011a1ab52d3aefbc9b8a4103d7574f4 
[2] 88cb5d85c41abb7ad99595ceb7c2fc98409dd4dc
[3] 25313021517412ce58072d798ccea29ba5d2f427 
[4] f2de2b4a6011a1ab52d3aefbc9b8a4103d7574f4 
[5] 88cb5d85c41abb7ad99595ceb7c2fc98409dd4dc 
[6] 25313021517412ce58072d798ccea29ba5d2f427
```

I want to replace these hashed values by numeric values keeping same number for same values, something like this:

```
Hashed_User_Id

[1] 1
[2] 2
[3] 3 
[4] 1
[5] 2
[6] 3
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: `as.integer(as.factor(Hashed_User_Id))`

Comment: Thanks Ronak, that worked!!

Comment: @RonakShah this could be a valid answer.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Trying to find a duplicate, couldn't find one. Not sure if I should post as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ronak suggested,

```
as.integer(as.factor(Hashed_User_Id))
```